# Draw line and put text in \begin{figure}

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this figure

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure_1.pdf}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

I want to draw two lines above it and put a text in the middle of the lines like the figure below.

[image]

I tried using the `\draw` function but it is impossible to have the lines I want. How do I do it ?

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-10,0) -- (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure_1.pdf}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Does the image file contain all six diagrams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
%    \begin{tikzpicture}
%    \draw (-10,0) -- (3,0);
%    \end{tikzpicture}
        \hspace{0.75cm}
        \begin{minipage}{.78\textwidth}
            \centering
            text

            \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
        \end{minipage}\hfill%
        \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}
            \centering
            text

            \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace{0.2cm}
        \vskip0.5em
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{NpPlW}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `%` isn't necessary at the end of a line ending with `\hfill`, since this command has only letters in its name. However, you should put one after `\hspace{0.75cm}`, where it is used at the end of a line. Then you will notice that without this extraneous space that you had, `\hspace` does nothing at the end of a line or of a paragraph. At this point, replace these `\hspace` calls with `\hspace*` and you should be good. The reason your end-of-paragraph `\hspace` commands work is because they are followed in your source by a space token (caused by the return to new line in source file)...

Comment: ... and TeX implicitly does an `\unskip` at the end of each paragraph, which removes this space token and leaves your `\hspace` command. So, this is a rather convoluted way of leaving space at the end of a paragraph; I'd suggest to use something like `\hspace*{0.2cm}\par`, which seems more straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using TikZ, offering a bunch of knobs for easy customization and rounded end points for the horizontal rules (this can be changed if desired, of course). This will be very convenient if you have several such legends to add, because for each legend, you only need to enter something like this:

```latex
\draw[legend=from (startpoint) to (endpoint)
      with offset \myRuleOffset and width \myRuleWidth node somenodename
      label text {Some text} offset by \myLabelOffset
      rule options {fill=blue!40} label options {color=red!20!black}];
```

The complete example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      legend/.style args={from #1to #2with offset #3and width #4node #5label
                          text #6 offset by #7rule options #8 label options #9}{%
        insert path={
          let \p1 = ($#1 + (0,#3) + (0,#4)$),
              \p2 = ($#2 + (0,#3)$)
          in
          node[inner sep=0, fit=(\p1) (\p2), rounded corners=0.5*#4,
               #8, label={[label distance=#7, anchor=base, #9]above:{#6}}]
            (#5) {}
          }}]

    % Parameters shared between our two legends
    \def\myRuleOffset{0.5cm}
    \def\myRuleWidth{2pt}
    \def\myLabelOffset{0.25cm}

    % The image node
    \node[inner sep=0] (img)
      { \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} };

    % The left legend stops a bit before two thirds of the image width
    \coordinate (rightEndOfLeftLegend) at
      ($ (img.north west)!0.65!(img.north east) $);
    % The right legends starts a bit after two thirds of the image width
    \coordinate (leftEndOfRightLegend) at
      ($ (img.north west)!0.68!(img.north east) $);

    % Left legend (creates a rectangle-shaped node named 'leftrule')
    \draw[legend=from (img.north west) to (rightEndOfLeftLegend)
          with offset \myRuleOffset and width \myRuleWidth node leftrule
          label text {Left label} offset by \myLabelOffset
          rule options {fill=blue!40} label options {color=red!20!black}];
    % Right legend (creates a rectangle-shaped node named 'rightrule')
    \draw[legend=from (leftEndOfRightLegend) to (img.north east)
          with offset \myRuleOffset and width \myRuleWidth node rightrule
          label text {Right label} offset by \myLabelOffset
          rule options {fill=orange!40} label options {color=red!20!black}];
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Your caption here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Zoom on two of the rule end points:

[image: Rule end points (zoomed)]

Of course, the above code doesn't depend on any `figure` environment—this environment is only used in the example for presentation purposes.